# Bad inputs, value not conserved

Tags: cardano-cli, daedalus, javascript

I have a `build raw` command witch worked very well. But the issue occured when i received some ada for testing purposes

when i run `cardano-cli query utxo --address $address --testnet-magic 1097911063` i get this

```
135cd17e0b9fa7080f9680da51addde5e87ebe9d977536506f37baf9d059677a     0        998685865 lovelace + 234234 1f49b6b44d9c1a8d7b9de0b95247baf757a7280809d144daf6630dc0.asdf + 23423234 30f7743917fb67c65df9689927f716ec368122192d9c6279afc1e958.cool + 234 4d23f4887865b4228a48f59db21d770e6bbc4a94c46c3c96dd72ad3c.asdf + 123123 711c6c84922194c8d2fe43d97769866a35b680c5c6513ac7bf0c19be.sfasfafasdasf + 234 8d4858089e488217d56834fde09d4038f7b675c61fdc883c4efe7934.ölkjasdölfkj + 123123 9c40937c4edf5acad2615b15f4516daad3eefc400913bc563139c5e3.sadfasf + 12234234 c85b75fbfe4810b60d3ff872c0124d811ed637810649800e14371976.asdfasf + TxOutDatumHashNone
23b147e31d0950f1b85b08a35dad87a994b8691598ea071d365248bd3033b50c     0        2391417 lovelace + TxOutDatumHashNone
4f778417a87663e311ff775909f65ba9f8124b4a964313554b8e261a68eca60b     0        2393485 lovelace + TxOutDatumHashNone
9346fa09dab6029344bc531dee5e57ca30d6cdaab04a7fbe69bd86a7d8fc0b9d     0        2007040 lovelace + 11230234 f662fa99ac8c3c9146f12ab34158a4b619c019f38336c3521ecceae1.öasldkfjaösl + TxOutDatumHashNone
a3e7934d43d0f3ae5aedc2d2f14cfb567cb848afc1647d2febe9be5ba1bc6d8b     0        2182573 lovelace + TxOutDatumHashNone
b46316a983cfdf81ed6785d7320feb23547746dea88b04b823c4f5d0d8e32d81     0        5000000 lovelace + TxOutDatumHashNone
```

This is my function how i build the raw transaction

```
public buildRaw(date: number,fee: number, address: string, txhash: string, txix: string, output: number, amount: number, policyid: string, tokenname: string,  tokens: { amount: number, tokenHash: string}[]): Promise<string>{
    let matxPath = "matx/" + date + ".raw"
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        exec(`cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
        --fee ${fee} \
        --tx-in ${txhash}#${txix} \
        --tx-out ${address}+${output}+"${amount} ${policyid}.${tokenname} ${tokens.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.amount.toString() + ' ' + curr.tokenHash + ' + ', '+ ').slice(0, -2)}" \
        --mint="${amount} ${policyid}.${tokenname}" \
        --minting-script-file policy/${date}.script \
        --out-file ${matxPath}`, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                rej(err)
            }
            res(matxPath)
        })
    })
}
```

I always use the first txhash `135cd17e0b9fa7080f9680da51addde5e87ebe9d977536506f37baf9d059677a` with the txix `0`

As i said this worked very well. But after i send myself some test ada, as you can see the other transactions, my code does not work anymore. Whats wrong with it?

According to the error i got `BadInputs` so i guess the problem is in the `--tx-in`. How do i need structure my `--tx-in` to make it work?

Comment: Are you calculating again your `txhash` and `txix` after you receive the test ada?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your tx-hash **AND** your tx-ix are being updated every time you use the function, especially if change is being sent back to yourself, which would raise the value of your tx-ix

Answer (score 0):

You can find the new UTxO with the help of the cli again after submitting a transaction. Otherwise, you are essentially trying to consume the same UTxO multiple times which is not possible.

```
cardano-cli transaction txid --tx-file $signedTxFile
```